# Asymptotics of the Number of Non-Isomorphic Equivalence Relations and the Number of Non-Isomorphic Relations

Tags: co.combinatorics, nt.number-theory

The number of non-isomorphic equivalence relations on a set of $n$ elements is the partition function
$$p(n) =\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{2}} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{h=1}^{k} \delta_{\gcd(h,k),1} \text{exp}\left(\pi i \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \frac{j}{k}\left(\frac{hj}{k} - \left\lfloor \frac{hj}{k} \right\rfloor - \frac{1}{2}\right) - \frac{2\pi i h n}{k} \right) \sqrt{k} \frac{d}{dn}\left[ \frac{\sinh\left(\frac{\pi}{k} \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}(n - \frac{1}{24})}\right)}{\sqrt{n - \frac{1}{24}}} \right]$$
The Hardy-Ramanujan asymptotic formula states that
$$p(n) \sim \frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}n}e^{\pi \sqrt{2n/3}}$$

By [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356995/counting-non-isomorphic-relations/357004#357004) (I would appreciate any reference to an actual derivation of this formula) the number of non-isomorphic relations on a set of $n$ elements is

$$a(n) = \sum_{1s_{1} + 2s_{2} + \cdot\cdot\cdot =n} \left(2^{\sum_{i,j \geq 1} \gcd(i,j)s_{i}s_{j}} \bigg/ \prod_{k=1} k^{s_{k}}s_{k}!\right)$$

I have no idea about the asymptotics of $a(n)$, but if you know of a reference that would be amazing. My question is whether anyone has researched, or if you have any idea about, whether or not
$$\frac{p(n)}{a(n)} \sim 0$$
I conjecture that it is asymptotic to zero, but I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: Consider a normal form for (the isomorphism classes of) the equivalence relations.  (I like to think of them as diagonal block matrices.)  There should be a region of "area" o(n) of unrelated elements, and in my picture a column of n/2 empty cells are guaranteed.  Toggling elements in this area should give you that your ratio is smaller than 2/n, and likely even smaller with more astute toggling.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Fibbonacci Matrices" Paseman, 2013.04.10

Comment: It appears to me that for every equivalence relation $E$ there are at least $n$ nonisomorphic ways of making a relation $R$ such that $E$ is generated by $R$. If so, then $\frac{p(n)}{a(n)}\le \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: The formula should be in Graphical Enumeration by Harary and Palmer, but I'm not sure.  You can find a (sketch of a) derivation in Section 2.2 of Combinatorial Species and Tree like structures by Bergeron, Labelle and Leroux.

Comment: @Tom: Consider the empty relation.

Comment: OK, I'm considering it. 

Comment: @Martin Rubey: Are you referring to the formula for $a(n)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need either of the two fancy formulas. Since every equivalence relation is the kernel of a function from the $n$-element set into itself, their number is at most $n^n$ (and taking them up to isomorphism can only make it smaller). On the other hand, there are $2^{n^2}$ binary relations in total, and each isomorphism class has at most $n!$ elements, hence there are at least $2^{n^2}/n!$ nonisomorphic relations. Thus,
$$\frac{p(n)}{a(n)}\le\frac{n^nn!}{2^{n^2}}=2^{O(n\log n)-n^2}\to0.$$

Comment: Algebra, pah!  Where is a lovely combinatorial proof?  Gerhard "Some Logicians Don't Appreciate Distinction" Paseman, 2013.04.10

Comment: I’d prefer “Some Logicians Don’t Bother With Sophistication If There Is An Easy Way To Get Things Done”.

Comment: This seems like a strange use of the term "kernel" to me.

Comment: Well, that’s how it is called in universal algebra (though here the algebra would be just a set with empty signature). Any better name?